# How to pass variable to session.attribute.contains() thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have some user roles which are passing through session attributes. I would like to check these roles in HTML file by variable name from properties.message. But it's showing EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'. How can I solve this problem?

My Controller class is as below:

```
Class RoleController{

    public void getDashboardInformation(Model model, HttpSession session) {
                session.setAttribute("roles", getUserRoleIds());
    }
 }
```

My message.properties.xml as below:

```
planner=4
sectionManager=5
```

My HTML file as below:

```html
<div class="custom-file upload-text-area">
  <input th:attrappend="disabled=${session.roles.contains(5)} ? '' : 'disabled'" type="file"        class="custom-file-input upload-text-area" id="CardFileName" name="CardFileName" accept=".csv">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">please insert</label>
</div>
 <span class="input-group-btn">
   <input th:attrappend="disabled=${session.roles.contains(4)} ? '' : 'disabled'" class="form-control" type="submit" value="submit"></span>
```

It works fine. But when I am going to replace 4 and 5 with message.properties value as below:

```html
    <div class="custom-file upload-text-area">
      <input th:attrappend="disabled=${session.roles.contains(#{sectionManager})} ? '' : 'disabled'" type="file"        class="custom-file-input upload-text-area" id="CardFileName" name="CardFileName" accept=".csv">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">please insert</label>
    </div>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input th:attrappend="disabled=${session.roles.contains(#{planner})} ? '' : 'disabled'" class="form-control" type="submit" value="submit"></span>
```

It is showing the following error:
**EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate this issue, and then resolve it by using the Thymeleaf [preprocessor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

For example:

```
th:attrappend="disabled=${session.roles.contains(__#{planner}__)} ? '' : 'disabled'"
```

My test case was simpler than yours but I think it should work for you. The preprocessor ensures the message expression is already evaluated (to an integer value, in your case), before the rest of the expression is evaluated.